# Listening for incoming links on Android with React-Native

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

I am able to listen and handle incoming links on IOS with react-native using the linking library: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html, but it shows the function for adding an event listener for a url is IOS platform specific. Are there any other ways of listening for incoming links to my app on android and handling it on the Javascript side?

Comment: [Deep Linking with React Native](http://ihor.burlachenko.com/deep-linking-with-react-native/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just got it working! You just have to follow [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html#adding-filters).

Basically, add an `<intent-filter>` under the existing one of your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`, containing the `VIEW` action, the `DEFAULT` and `BROWSABLE` categories, and at least a `<data>`.

Then simply rebuild and reinstall your APK (`react-native run-android`), that's it! Links matching your `<data>` tags will now open in your app!

Now just catch this URL with [Linking.getInitialURL()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html#getinitialurl) in the `componentDidMount()` of your main Javascript class!

Example of manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="net.yourapp"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="0.1">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

  <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>

      <!-- HERE: -->
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="yoursite.net" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="yoursite.com" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="yoursite" />
        <data android:scheme="customscheme" android:host="yourpath" />
      </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
  </application>

</manifest>
```