# Getting Text Selection from Other Apps to My App

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I am learning `React Native` by building a project and using Expo. I am trying to show my app in the context menu whenever the text is selected in other apps i.e browser, messaging, etc. On tapping my app, it should open my app & I want to be able to get that text.

**Progress so far**

I got it partially working for Android by adding the following intent filter under the `android` key in `app.json`

```json
"intentFilters": [
  {
    "action": "PROCESS_TEXT",
    "data": {
      "mimeType": "text/plain"
    },
    "category": [
      "DEFAULT"
    ]
  }
]
```

**Problem**

For Android, I can see my app and tap open it as well. How do I access the selected text within my app?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653723/listening-for-incoming-links-on-android-with-react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know, it is not possible at the [expo go](https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/#managed-workflow). you can do this in expo bare or [React Native CLI](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

you can use [react-native-process-text-intent](https://github.com/numandev1/react-native-process-text-intent) package

### Installation

```bash
npm install react-native-process-text-intent
```

## Usage

```
import { getProcessTextIntent } from 'react-native-process-text-intent';

// ...

getProcessTextIntent()
  .then((textResult) => {
    if (textResult) {
      console.log(textResult, 'ProcessedText');   // here will be your processed Text coming from android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT intent-filter
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

first you need to add this `intent-filter` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

[image]

Comment: it was working below android 11 .after it not working.

Comment: Not working on Android 13, and the latest react native cli until commenting day.